# Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

guys i have a column which contains text and button and what i want is when click on the button the text changed .. here is my code

```js
var count = 0;
$(document).ready(function() {
      $("#jqGrid").jqGrid({
        data: data.rows,
        datatype: "local",
        styleUI: "Bootstrap",
        colModel: [

          {
            label: 'Customer ID',
            name: 'CustomerID',
            width: 180,
            editable: true,
            edittype: "custom",
            id: "CustomerID",
            editoptions: {
              custom_element: function(value, options) {
                var parts = value.split(' ');
                var elemStr = '<div><input size="6" id="txt_"' + count + '" value="' + parts[0] +
                  '" /><input type="button" size="5" value="..." onclick="setText();"/></div>';

                count++;

                // return DOM element from jQuery object
                return $(elemStr)[0];
              },
              custom_value: function(elem) {
                var inputs = $("input", $(elem)[0]);
                var first = inputs[0].value;
                return first;
              }
            }
          },

        ],

      });
     });

      function setText() {
        document.getElementById("txt_" + count).innerHTML = "hey";
      }
```

so why it gives me that exception ? .. plz help .. btw i am beginner

Comment: Are you sure you have element with `id="text_0"`?

Comment: 'txt_ + count' not' text_0'

Comment: put a debugger; in first line of setText(){} method, open a console (f12) in your browser and check if your 'txt_' exists

Answer (score 0):

the count inside setText is undefined.

1st change onclick function of button to pass the count variable

```
 var elemStr = '<div><input size="6" id="txt_"' + count + '" value="' + parts[0] +
                  '" /><input type="button" size="5" value="..." onclick="setText(' + count + ');"/></div>';
```

then accept the count as parameter

```
function setText(count) {
        document.getElementById("txt_" + count).innerHTML = "hey";
      }
```

Comment: inspect the elements if the html generated properly, i.e. the ids of input are set txt_0, txt_1 and onclick calls like setText(0), setText(1) respectively

Answer (score 0):

You can pass count to the function:

```
var count = 0;
$(document).ready(function() {
      $("#jqGrid").jqGrid({
        data: data.rows,
        datatype: "local",
        styleUI: "Bootstrap",
        colModel: [

          {
            label: 'Customer ID',
            name: 'CustomerID',
            width: 180,
            editable: true,
            edittype: "custom",
            id: "CustomerID",
            editoptions: {
              custom_element: function(value, options) {
                var parts = value.split(' ');
                var elemStr = '<div><input size="6" id="txt_"' + count + '" value="' + parts[0] +
                  '" /><input type="button" size="5" value="..." onclick="setText(' + count + ');"/></div>';

                count++;

                // return DOM element from jQuery object
                return $(elemStr)[0];
              },
              custom_value: function(elem) {
                var inputs = $("input", $(elem)[0]);
                var first = inputs[0].value;
                return first;
              }
            }
          },

        ],

      });
     });

      function setText(count) {
        document.getElementById("txt_" + count).innerHTML = "hey";
      }
```